# Is it okay to publish credentials for an IAM user with NO permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to create an IAM user that can activate the JS SDK on the clientside that allows anyone (intentionally) to upload files to a specific s3 Bucket.

In order to use the SDK, I need to give it credentials.

Is it okay to to publish keys for an IAM user with ZERO permissions to simply activate the SDK?

Security will be handled on the bucket policy.

Comment: *"In order to use the SDK, I need to give it credentials."*  That doesn't sound right.  For example, [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html) has no such requirement.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks, but from the first line "Let's get started with the SDK for JavaScript by creating a simple browser-based app that authenticates users using web identity federation and Facebook login."  I also don't want to have to ask users to authenticate with FB or any other form of auth.

Comment: I didn't say you did, and that isn't the point I intended to make.  That is an example of using the SDK in a way that does not require an AWS access key ID or secret -- it uses an IAM role.

Comment: ahhh, I see.  Is there a way to gain access to a Federated ID without any sort of auth step?  I guess I could use cognito to make an anonymous user but that seems like a big extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use an anonymous cognito-identity pool and the cognito-identity credentials provider? it was designed largely for this purpose.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html

Notice there is an unauthenticated or "anonymous" mode

Comment: While I didn't want to involve Cognito, AWS notified me that exposing secret keys publicly violates the AWS Customer Agreement.  So even if it isn't a security issue, it is a legal one.

Comment: @MichaelPell alternatively if you have a way of keeping a presigned url fresh (refreshed before expiration) you can simply do an http put to the presigned url.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up.  I'll take a look at that.  I'm also considering a lambda.  But Anonymous cognito doesn't seem to be much trouble

Comment: @MichaelPell you'd still need a way to get credentials to call the lambda. That also means you have to transfer the data twice (which is a higher bill), if you want to go that route Api gateway may be a better long-term option.

Comment: yeah exactly, I would expose it with API Gateway.  Do you know of a way to produce the signed URL w/o anything on the serverside?